Burninate [doraemon] tag?
I'm going to bet that this burnination request is not controversial. Nevertheless I'll pay my respects to my fellow users.
This tag is used in 7 questions (4 of which are closed) by the same asker, who was apparently translating comics into Chinese.
According to the guidelines, tags are:

a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

I'm going to make the case that the tag isn't sufficiently relatable to the Chinese language, and doesn't allow for a wide enough population of "experts" to meaningfully fit the guidelines quoted above.
For reference:

(n.) 的大預言 having trouble making sense of this construct
Character Gaps On Comic Conversation : 6
Character Gaps On Comic Conversation : 5
Character Gaps On Comic Conversation : 4
Character Gaps On Comic Conversation : 3
Translation Gaps On Comic Conversation : 2
Translation Gaps On Comic Conversation : 1


I definitely want to burninate this one.

@Becky李蓓 done...
